# Centos 7 apache displaying php source code after installing SSL Cert via LetsEncrypt

Tags: wordpress, lets-encrypt

After installing ssl certs on my digital ocean droplet, and moving my WordPress dir to public_html folder, only php source code is being displayed instead of content.  [My url is](https://rafikirestaurantandlounge.com/)

I appreciate any help.

Even after rebuilding my droplet and removing SSL certs I still get the same problem.

Here is my sites-available/domain.conf file. On my droplet, SeLinux is disabled, .htaccess has 755 permissions and still

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.rafikirestaurantandlounge.com
    ServerAlias rafikirestaurantandlounge.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/rafikirestaurantandlounge.com/html
   <Directory "/var/www/rafikirestaurantandlounge.com/html">
        Require all granted
        # Allow local .htaccess to override Apache configuration settings
        AllowOverride all
  </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/www/rafikirestaurantandlounge.com/log/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/rafikirestaurantandlounge.com/log/requests.log combined
   </VirtualHost>
```

And here is my .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

All Directory settings in httpd.conf remain the same.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: can you redirect ssl in htaccess ? i think ssl not installed or problem is for htaccess redirect . check email for verify ssl or account for ssl

Comment: SSL is installed, but when moving my WordPress set-up, .htaccess was not in the destination folder. I tried to re-create it with basic configs but did not work. Because of time constraints, I decided to rebuild the droplet.

Comment: can you give tree of folder and directory and sample of htaccess ?

Comment: Are you sure Apache is running? Please check `systemctl status httpd`

Comment: httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-01-08 18:35:17 EAT; 6min ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 8696 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 8699 (httpd)

Comment: Httpd is running

Comment: Yes I can access your site over `http` indeed. Please follow this tutorial on DO [/how to secure apache with lets encrypt on centos-7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-centos-7) try to copy/paste all the commands sequentially and watch your log to see if it fail.